# refresh datatable with new data angular

Tags: angularjs, datatable, reload

I have a datatable with some questions and answers in. When the page is loaded "aviation.json" is put in the datatable. After selecting another value in the combobox the data in the datatable needs to be updated. But this doesn't work, does somebody know what I do wrong?

## HTML

Select your category:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table ng-table-rowselected" id="questionsTable">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data"
        ng-click="user.$selected = !user.$selected; changeSelection(user)"
        ng-class="{'active': user.$selected}">
        <td data-title="'Category'" sortable="'Category'" filter="{ 'Category': 'text' }">
            {{user.Category}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Question'" sortable="'Question'" filter="{ 'Question': 'text' }">
            {{user.Question}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## Code

$scope.$watch('comboCat', function(){
        console.log($scope.comboCat.name);

```
    switch ($scope.comboCat.name){
        case "Aviation": console.log("aviaton selected");
            $http.get('aviation.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                console.log("get json aviaton");
            });
            break;
        case "Customer care": console.log("customer care selected");
            //$scope.data = $http.get('customerCare.json');
            $http.get('customerCare.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            });
            break;
        case "Finance": console.log("Finance selected");
            $http.get('finance.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: How did you go with this @Warri?